# Is it needed for the server daemon to running so that it could be included as a dependency while building some other package?

Tags: linux, configure, lfs, sqlserver

I'm making the postfix MTA which depends on some database packages(mariadb, postgresql,...). I'm building on the instructions of Beyond Linux Form Scratch (BLFS) but I fear if it is needed for the sever daemons to be running for the build.
Also, I've also built and installed some such packages (cyrus sasl, open ldap, ...) before and I do fear if they are built with mariadb, postgresql and all.
Please help!

---

Clarification from comments: I've already installed mariadb, postgresql, and now I'm moving to install the postfix mail agent. And, postfix has mariadb and postgresql as dependencies. Now, is it required for mysql server and postgresql server to be running so that that it could be included as a dependency in postfix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install from source you only need the libraries, not the actual binaries. So for instance, if you want to manually compile postfix then you only need to install the development packages, or to manually compile the dependencies. However, if you manually compile dependencies, you have to know that they usually go under /usr/local/lib if no --prefix provided. if the prefix was provided, then you need to specify the path in /etc/ld.so.conf and then run the ldconfig command to update the locations of the libraries. Even so, it's a good idea to run that command after manually compiling libraries.

And to answer your question, No, it is not necessary for the daemons to run in order to compile anything. The only requirement is that the libraries of the dependencies are installed.